# Differences between Multipart and Form in terms of client upload

Tags: asp.net, http, azure, iis-7

I created C# client with `HttpClient` library.

I use BASE64 encoded data in order to upload file (via POST).
Sometimes, I experienced errors (maybe because of content length limit) even the data is not too big (around 500kB).

I changed it to [`MultipartFormData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193686.aspx) POST, and as we expected, it runs OK with more than 1MB.

Does the web server treat sessions differently bewteen simple Form POST and Multipart POST?

Note that the web service I use is Azure WebSites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not any kind of limitation in Azure, or IIS. This is how HTTP protocol is designed! Read more about different type of content type for `Form` elements [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4).

From the Specification:

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> This is the default content type. Forms submitted with this content
>   type must be encoded as follows:
>
> Control names and values are escaped. Space characters are replaced by
>   `+', and then reserved characters are escaped as described in
>   [RFC1738], section 2.2: Non-alphanumeric characters are replaced by`
>   %HH', a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing the
>   ASCII code of the character. Line breaks are represented as "CR LF"
>   pairs (i.e., `%0D%0A')....

Now for Multipart:

> multipart/form-data
>
> The content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is inefficient
>   for sending large quantities of binary data or text containing
>   non-ASCII characters. The content type "multipart/form-data" should be
>   used for submitting forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and
>   binary data.
>
> The content "multipart/form-data" follows the rules of all multipart
>   MIME data streams as outlined in [RFC2045]. The definition of
>   "multipart/form-data" is available at the [IANA] registry.

So, to upload files, you should always use `multipart/form-data`. Not just with Azure, not just with IIS, but with **any** hosting provider and **any** web server that implements the HTTP protocol standard.